# What problems can leaving a PHP tag inside a function cause?

Tags: php

You would expect this function to print the name in a browser, and it does:

```
<?php
function name(){
    $var = 'Doe';
    ?>
    John <?php echo $var;
}
name();
?>
```

Could this type of function be used as a method of a PHP class, and is this bad code practice?

Comment: How many people do you think can figure out what this does without scratching their heads? That's at least 3 WTF on my [scale](http://www.osnews.com/images/comics/wtfm.jpg).

Comment: this is definitely no good practice, that's for sure.

Comment: @netcoder agreed, but is seeing everywhere (almost)

Comment: @netcoder - what's your problem with someone asking a question?

Comment: @Owen: What makes you think I have a problem with someone asking a question? o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no [syntax] problem but I hardly can imagine a case when I can use such a code.

Answer (score 0):

If you think to use an arquitecture like MVC or writting code in OOP, or any of the best practices in the software development, that code is a bad idea becouse you are mixing presentation with logic.

Comment: The example does not show any business logic, it's presentation only.

Comment: why do you need a function like this in the presentation layer? (only curiosity)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem or bad practice in PHP. It is especially useful when you need to loop over things that have large output. For example, I might do this in a class:

```
function print() {
  /* Lets say we have an array of questions and answers like this:
       $question->$answer
     It will be called $qa
  */

  foreach($qa as $question->$answer) {
    ?><h1><? echo $question; ?></h1>
    <?php if('' != $answer) ?>
      <p> This question has an answer! </p>
    <p><? echo $answer; ?> </p>
    <?
  }
}
```

This is a fairly bad example, but I needed something on the fly, and this is what I came up with.

If you do something complicated here, it will be more confusing than any other method, but does shorten your code by quite a bit, and keeps everything in one place.

However, your example shows a poor usage of this practice, so I would not use it in your case.